# How can i install laravel?

Tags: php, xampp

I have instruction, but the problem is when I install xampp and  enter ( php - v )in the cmd shows me :Could not open input file: -
I have already read about the adding environment variables and done this but unfortunately it still can't find it.
What can i do ?

Comment: I wouldn't do this alone to check php version ..   Create a file `phpinfo.php` and add the following: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`

Comment: Should be closed as typo.

Comment: @trincot Yes, and I'm voting that way, but I'm also going to answer it as it strikes me that plenty of other people will make this typo if they're not used to unix commands...

Answer (score 1):

It's `php -v`. Note the lack of a space between the - and the 'v'. What the error message is telling you is literally "Could not open input file: -", that is, the PHP interpreter is running fine, but it's trying to open a file called '-' because of the extra space you put in.

Answer (score 1):

The commando don't have a space between the `-` and the `v`.

```
php -v
```

But this will not necessarily mean the version of php used by XAMPP is this one. XAMPP can be using another version under the hood.

A better way is creating a `.php` file and accessing using XAMPP - probably in `http://localhost` - with the code:

```
<?php
phpinfo()
?>
```